# How to identify a DIV without using an ID or a class name

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-selectors

So I just need a reminder,

Every element can only have 1 id, but multiple classes are possible,

But what if I would like to have 2 ways to uniquely identify an object without classes?

I cant remember the name of it, something like Tagname, that can be used in addition to ID.

And how would you identify this object in jQuery?

For classes it is: $('.class'), for ID's it is $('#id') but what about this thing that I am vaguely describing?

Taylor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I cant remember the name of it,
>   something like Tagname, that can be
>   used in addition to ID.

You might be thinking of GetElementsByTagName() but that will return a collection:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName.

You can use arbitrary attributes in any modern browser (jQuery does this behind the scenes). So you can put whatever attribute you want on an element and locate it using a jQuery attribute selector (as @Dave pointed out in his answer).

```
<div myAttribute="foo"></div>

<script>

var element = $("div[myAttribute='foo']"); // matches all divs with "myAttribute" set

</script>
```

There are many options: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 2):

Just use the "name" attribute:

```
<div id="something" name="something"></div>
```

Then reference it by the id like usual, or by the name like this:

```
$('[name="something"]')
```

[Info on on this selector here.](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: how would I identify this using a jquery selector?

Comment: Thanks! I will test the reference

Comment: You shouldn't use `name` unless it's an `input` or other form element.  It might still work, but it's not correct in modern HTML.

Comment: @Jacob, It still does work. What's the deal with using `name` other than form elements?

Comment: I should clarify... `name` is deprecated in XHTML.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.10.  If you don't care about that sort of thing, it doesn't really matter.